# Using reduce without return keyword by looking for unique values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I like to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for several different scenarios in my code, it's pretty straightforward and handy.

Please observe in the 2 different solutions below the `reduce()` function takes 2 different initial values, in the first case is `new Set()` and the second is `[]`.

In the below example the code uses `reduce()` **without** `return` keyword - `Set` one:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => a.add(c), new Set());
console.log(Array.from(result));
```

The next example is using still `reduce()` but here **with** a `return` keyword - `Array` one:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  a.find(e => e === c) ? null : a.push(c);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

***Question:***

So the [`.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) function for `Set` returns the `Set` object itself. The [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function for `Array` returns the `length` of the used `Array`.

The `Set` case helps me to shorten the code using `.reduce()` without `return` keyword because the above mentioned reason. In my second example I would like to use the solution without `return` keyword but still with `Array` somehow.

Is there any workaround solution to get the same result but without using `return` keyword in the second example? I would like to shorten the code further if possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take either the accumulator, if found or concat the element to the accumulator.

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => a.find(e => e === c) ? a : a.concat(c), []);

console.log(result);
```

Just to mention, `Set` takes a complete array with the constructor.

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = Array.from(new Set(data));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `concat()` works as expected. I was using `Set` in that way for better representation in my example but thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) can add a new item to an array and returns a new array, so can works similar to `Set#add`. However, it still needs the conditional operator since you want to either add an element or nothing - for the latter case that's concatenating an array with an empty array:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(a.some(e => e === c) ? [] : c), []);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to again combine two arrays:

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'k', 'b'];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...(a.some(e => e === c) ? [] : c)], []);
console.log(result);
```

Neither of the two is perfect, to be honest. The existence of the conditional operator makes this harder to read when all one line but it's still an option.